# Figure numbering with section number, problem with subfigure

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats

I changed my figure numbering to section-style numbering for my thesis:

```
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
```

That's fine, but the only problem that remains in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfigure[First temperature cycle. We measured additionally at +1$^{\circ}$C.]{
\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{./figures/mu_vs_v_1st.pdf}
\label{fig:mu_vs_v_1st}
}\\
\subfigure[Second temperature cycle. Note the difference to the first cycle of     1$^{\circ}$C in the highest temperature measured.]{
\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{./figures/mu_vs_v_2nd.pdf}
\label{fig:mu_vs_v_2nd}
}
\label{fig:mu_vs_v}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here I get the section style numbering for the figure as a whole (Fig. 5.3 - the figure being the third one in Section 5) but I get Fig. 7(a) and 7(b) for referral straight to the subfigures (the figure being the seventh in the whole thesis).

What should I change to get Fig. 5.3(a) and 5.3(b) for the subfigures as well? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redefine `\p@subfigure` which controls the prefix used for the cross-references to subfigures:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{\thefigure}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\section{Test Section}

A reference to subfigures~\ref{fig:mu_vs_v_1st} and~\ref{fig:mu_vs_v_2nd}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfigure[First temperature cycle. We measured additionally at +1$^{\circ}$C.]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{./figures/mu_vs_v_1st.pdf}
\label{fig:mu_vs_v_1st}%
}\\
\subfigure[Second temperature cycle. Note the difference to the first cycle of     1$^{\circ}$C in the highest temperature measured.]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{./figures/mu_vs_v_2nd.pdf}
\label{fig:mu_vs_v_2nd}
}
\caption{test figure with subfigures}
\label{fig:mu_vs_v}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

By the way, `subfigure` is an obsolete package. You should consider using [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead.

Using the `subfig` package has an additional advantage: you don't need to redefine `\p@subfigure` since internally the package does this for you:

[image]

```
\documentclass[english,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[listofformat=subparens]{subfig}

\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document} 

\section{Test Section}

A reference to subfigures~\ref{fig:mu_vs_v_1st} and~\ref{fig:mu_vs_v_2nd}. And another reference to subfigures~\ref{fig:mu_vs_v}\subref{fig:mu_vs_v_1st} and~\ref{fig:mu_vs_v}\subref{fig:mu_vs_v_2nd}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[First temperature cycle. We measured additionally at +1$^{\circ}$C.\label{fig:mu_vs_v_1st}]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{./figures/mu_vs_v_1st.pdf}}\\
\subfloat[Second temperature cycle. Note the difference to the first cycle of $1^{\circ}$C in the highest temperature measured.\label{fig:mu_vs_v_2nd}]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{./figures/mu_vs_v_2nd.pdf}}
\caption{test figure with subfigures}
\label{fig:mu_vs_v}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```